# installing 7zip from terminal not working?

Tags: command-line, system-installation

installed  **7zip**, from the following code :-

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip
```

It asked for my password and it proceeded to download the package.
 But it is not found in unity menu.What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p7zip and p7zip-full command-line programs use the Archive Manager application as a GUI front-end. Archive Manager is installed by default in Ubuntu. You can open Archive Manager from the Dash or by right-clicking a compressed archive and from the popup context menu selecting *Open With Archive Manager*.

Comment: I understand we have a archive manager, but why I am a given a option to install 7zip in the ubuntu software center. Shouldn't it have a check(green tick for installed application) then? Or does it bring new features to the archive manager?

Comment: Archive Manager is only a GUI front-end, so a back-end program(s) is also needed. There are several back-end programs in the Ubuntu repositories, which support different file formats, including tar, zip, p7zip, unrar and p7zip-rar.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Can you name what 7zip provides more than what is offered by default? or is there any other program I can use as front for the gui?

Comment: @WhatIfTheyGetMe The default supports bzip2, gzip and zip compression. 7zip adds 7zip compression. [Other utilities available include](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/file-roller) lzma, xz, ace, etc.

Comment: Great answer. I am marking this thread solved. Thank you karel and thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

`p7zip` is a CLI program so it will work only from command line, that is the reason you are not getting it in the dash or via graphical interface.

Quoting from [`man p7zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/p7zip.1):

> p7zip is a gzip-like CLI wrapper script for 7zip